# How do I set up a JSON data set that can be accessed offline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, search

I am trying to build a mobile application with multiple pages that users can use and navigate offline. It will have a search function to look for certain pages within itself. In previous questions I was told setting up JSON data sets is the best way to do this; however, every example or tutorial or book I read about JSON data sets and accessing them all have to do with come communication with a server and browser. How would I set up the JSON data set and set up the ability for users to interact with it or call in via  to access the JSON data set offline? I just assume that it would be different than setting it up like the examples I've seen so far

Comment: If `LocalStorage` is available, you could store a stringified version of your data.

Comment: You could store `JSON` within `html` document or use `WebWorker` to serve `JSON` to local `html` documents utilizing `postMessage`

Comment: Store all you JSON data into a single column in your respected database, that you can use offline for a long time and also you will not lost your data after clearing your browser history or Cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage to store the JSON data in the browser.

Let's say you have a file on the server called `data.json` with the following content:

```
[{ "name":"Name1", "surname":"Surname1" },
 { "name":"Name2", "surname":"Surname2"},
 { "name":"Name3", "surname":"Surname3" },
 { "name":"Name4", "surname":"Surname4" }]
```

When a user access the mobile application **for the first time** you can make a call to the server,get the JSON data and store it in the browser using `localStorage`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
            localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Google Chrome -> Resource -> Local Storage:

[image: localStorage in Google Chrome]

Now that your JSON object is stored locally you can retrieve it from local storage and use it in your application without connecting to the server.Just make sure you always do a null check to make sure the data still exists locally, if it doesn't you would need to initiate a server call:

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

if (users != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        alert(users[i].name + " " + users[i].surname);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is awesome, thank you very much, very clear thorough explination

Comment: the only question I have, can you explain a bit more about what this line is doing? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It adds a reference to the jQuery library on the CDN.So instead of hosting the jQuery library file as part of your website you use the CDN and let someone else host it for you.I just always use it in the answers I post on Stackoverflow so that usesr can just copy and paste the code I post and it will work.

Comment: ah okay I see, thank you for explaining that, you've been a big help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite to save the data you already grabbed. So you can decide to grab the whole data again when the user is online or you only grab the new content:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Another possibility is to download your data as .json file and load it in your app. So you'll need the read and write permissions of users.